# Hyperledger-fabric blockchain with chaincode accessible publicly

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to create a hyperledger-fabric public chaincode, and I don't know if there is an exact way to do it, the solution I am using is with an `express` server that will be connected to the fabric network using a wallet, an return results for users using http.

Is this solution correct? Or are there better solutions?